# Operator topologies on $L^{\infty}(X,\mu )$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $(X,\mu )$ be a measure space.  Then, $L^2(X):=L^2(X,\mu )$ is a Hilbert space in the usual way and we may view $L^{\infty}(X):=L^{\infty}(X,\mu )$ as a subalgebra of bounded operators on $L^2(X)$ via $L^{\infty}(X)\ni f\mapsto M_f$, where $M_f\colon L^2(X)\rightarrow L^2(X)$ is the multiplication operator defined by $[M_f(g)](x):=f(x)g(x)$.

Regarding $L^{\infty}(X)$ as an algebra of bounded operators in this way, the question can be stated as

> How can we describe explicitly convergence in the various [operator topologies](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Operator_topologies) on $L^{\infty}(X)$?

At least one is relatively easy.  For example, $\lambda \mapsto M_{f_{\lambda}}$ converges to $M_f$ in the operator norm topology iff $\lambda \mapsto f_{\lambda}$ converges to $f$ in the $L^{\infty}$ norm.  It seems that [convergence in measure corresponds to ultra-weak convergence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137609/von-neumann-algebras-and-measurable-spaces).  Furthermore, [pointwise almost-everywhere convergence can't correspond to any topology](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/245b-notes-11-the-strong-and-weak-topologies/).  These are perhaps the three most obvious notions of convergence in $L^{\infty}(X)$, but that leaves many operator topologies unaccounted for.  Perhaps most of them just don't have a very nice description?

**Update #1**:  It seems as if the weak operator topology corresponds to the weak-$^*$ topology:  $\lambda \mapsto f_{\lambda}\in L^{\infty}(X)$ converges to $f\in L^{\infty}(X)$ in the weak-$^*$ topology iff $\lambda \mapsto \int _Xgf_{\lambda}$ converges to $\int _Xgf$ for all $g\in L^1(X)$, and on the other hand, $\lambda \mapsto M_{f_{\lambda}}$ converges to $M_f$ in the weak operator topology iff $\lambda \mapsto \int _Xgf_{\lambda}h$ converges to $\int  _Xgfh$ for all $g,h\in L^2(X)$.  As $gh\in L^1(X)$ for $g,h\in L^2(X)$, we obtain the $(\Rightarrow )$ direction immediately.  For the $(\Leftarrow )$ write $g=u|g|$ for some Borel function $u$ with $|u|=1$, so that we have $\lambda \mapsto \int _Xgf_{\lambda}=\int _X(u|g|^{1/2})f_{\lambda}|g|^{1/2}$ converges to $\int _X(u|g|^{1/2})f|g|^{1/2}=\int _Xgf$.

**Update #2**:  I have decided to ask this on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258829/operator-topologies-on-l-inftyx-mu).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can learn something related to von Neumann algebra.

$L^2(X,\mu)$ is a Hilbert space. You can verify that $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is a maximal abelian von Neumann algebra on $L^2(X,\mu)$.

By von Neumann bicommutant theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem), $M$ is a von Neumann algebra on Hilbert space $H$ iff $M$ is closed in strong operator topology  iff $M$ is closed in weak operator topology.

Comment: This is only true if $(X,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, right?